# How can I efficiently add data from dictionaries to a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Inside a for loop I'm populating a dataframe using a dictionary that's returned from a function. Perhaps I'm not searching with the correct terminology or my approach to this problem is wrong, but I haven't been able to find a solution online that's applicable. I think the way I'm currently doing this is very inefficient.

I'm fairly inexperienced with Pandas - I've experimented a little attempting to use the merge method, as well as a few combinations of concat, append, and remove_duplicates, but I haven't quite managed what I want.

My current solution to this is to iterate over the dictionary items:

```py
for company in Company.instances:
    for resource in company.resources:
        for product in resource["product"]:
            my_dictionary = my_function("with varying args per company/product")

            # Remove None values from my_dictionary
            my_dictionary = {k: v for k, v in my_dictionary.copy().items() if v is not None}

            # TODO speed this up
            if len(my_dictionary) > 0:
                df = Company.products[product]["current"]
                for subproduct, value in my_dictionary.items():
                    df.loc[
                        (df["product"] == product) &
                        (df["subproduct"] == subproduct),
                        company.name
                    ] = value
```

Things to note:

Each of the dataframes in the Company class at `Company.products[product]["current"]` are initialised with one product per dataframe in this format:

```
        product     subproduct  company1    company2
0       a           1
1       a           2
2       a           3
3       a           4
4       a           5
```

Dictionary keys refer to the subproduct column. It's possible to have two or more dictionaries for each company column in the dataframe - for example:

```py
"""
if my_function returns this dict for company1:
{'1': 'alpha', '2': 'bravo', '3': 'charlie'}

desired:
        product     subproduct  company1    company2
0       a           1           alpha
1       a           2           bravo
2       a           3           charlie       
3       a           4                       
4       a           5

followed by this dict also for company1:
{'1': 'november', '5': 'echo'}

desired:
        product     subproduct  company1    company2
0       a           1           november
1       a           2           bravo
2       a           3           charlie       
3       a           4                       
4       a           5           echo

and this dict for company2:
{'4': 'kilo', '2': 'foxtrot'}

desired:
        product     subproduct  company1    company2
0       a           1           november
1       a           2           bravo       foxtrot
2       a           3           charlie       
3       a           4                       kilo
4       a           5           echo

"""
```

Thanks for taking the time to read, here's a pastebin if you want to save a minute or two recreating the dataframe structure and copying the dicts: https://pastebin.com/raw/KkF77LCG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on using `update` to efficiently update the column of
choice (e.g. *company1*).

But to use `update`, you should have a *Series* with keys equal to particular
keys (index values) in *df*, whereas all your dictionaries have keys equal
to *subproduct* values, for particular *product*.

So the key to success is to "translate":

- from *product* / *subproduct* values,
- to index values.

To do it efficiently, start with creation of a **reverse index** for *df*:

```
revInd = df.reset_index().set_index(['product', 'subproduct'])['index']
```

The idea is that having *product* / *subproduct* pair, you can quickly
get the index of the relevant row in *df* (executing *df.loc[...]* is much slower).

To check how it works, run `revInd[('a', '1')]` and you will get *0* - the
index of row with *product == 'a'* and *subproduct = '1'*
(I assumed that both these columns are of *string* type).

Then define the updating function:

```
def updCol(df, revInd, prodName, colName, dct):
    upd = pd.Series({ revInd[(prodName, k)]: v for k, v in dct.items() })
    df[colName].update(upd)
```

Parameters:

- *df* - the DataFrame to update.
- *revInd* - the reversed index.
- *prodName* - product name (a part of the selection criterion).
- *colName* - column name to update.
- *dct* - the source dictionary.

This function generates *upd* Series, from a dictionary comprehension,
which performs transcoding from *product* / *subproduct* pairs
(subproduct from dictionary key), to indices of relevant rows in *df*.
Values are not changed.

Then, based on *upd*, the relevant column in *df* is updated.
This update occurs in-place, so there is no need to return any result.

To check my solution, create "updating" dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'1': 'alpha', '2': 'bravo', '3': 'charlie'}
d2 = {'1': 'november', '5': 'echo'}
d3 = {'4': 'kilo', '2': 'foxtrot'}
```

(*d1* and *d2* for *company1* and *d3* for *company2*).

Then run:

```
updCol(df, revInd, 'a', 'company1', d1)
updCol(df, revInd, 'a', 'company1', d2)
updCol(df, revInd, 'a', 'company2', d3)
```

If you print *df*, you will get:

```
  product subproduct  company1 company2
0       a          1  november         
1       a          2     bravo  foxtrot
2       a          3   charlie         
3       a          4               kilo
4       a          5      echo
```

just as it should be.

For demonstration purpose, run *print(df)* also after the first and second
call of *updCol*.

Of course, I was not able to replicate the whole task you shoud do.
I showed only how to use the above function on your sample data.

So now it is your task to incorporate my solution into your code.